# How not to show ads to paid customers when I decided to make it free?

Tags: unity, game-mechanics

I am planning to publish a paid game built with Unity. After a while I will update the game as free and will start showing ads. But I do not want my first paid customers to see the ads after installing update? How can I manage this?

Game will be both on App Store and Google Play.

Thanks

Comment: The people who paid will feel cheated when it goes free.

Comment: I'm guessing one approach would be however people do it to remove ads by purchasing an upgrade in the game. Maybe lookup tutorials about that

Comment: Or... start by having a free (with ads) and a pro (without ads). Or if the players need to be connected, check on the server if they bought the pro version and disable the ad when the app launches...

Comment: Only way I can think of saving some information post update is to have a server side component. Barring that, @AlexandreVaillancourt's idea is the simplest option. <Game Name> Free version, <Game Name> premium ad free version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution: you can store the initial version number of the game at installation in PlayerPrefs. Then when you add the ads, you can have a check of the minimum version number versus the initial version number. Or you can record in PlayerPrefs whether it is a paid version or not on the initial launch again.

That leaves some problems: what if someone uninstall the paid version and reinstalls the free version? You might need a way to grant them the "no-ads" flags remotely. I use in-game gift codes for that, but it requires a backend of some sort (using parse.com).

It is also susceptible to hacking of the local data, but if someone is willing to go to that length, it doesn't matter what you do - so don't worry about that.

Comment: The idea is good can work with file serialization instead of playerprefs. Serialized files are secure. Instead of version number,  he could use some other identifier since if game is updated, it's version number will also change.